# Best way to write db results as csv file to aws s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, java-8

Need suggestions for best way to write database results as csv file to aws s3 bucket. 
Note: the csv data may grow form kb to gb in size.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be:

- Write your data to a CSV file on your local computer (or wherever your app is running)
- Upload the file to an Amazon S3 bucket using the [AWS SDK for Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/?id=docs_gateway)

Please note that it is not possible to *append* data to an Amazon s3 object. So, you should either upload a new file each time or, if you want all data in one file, you will need to re-upload the complete file each time.

If you want to send the data as a **stream**, you can use [`putObject()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#putObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.io.InputStream-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata-):

```java
public PutObjectResult putObject(String bucketName,
                                 String key,
                                 InputStream input,
                                 ObjectMetadata metadata)
                          throws SdkClientException,
                                 AmazonServiceException
```

Comment: Can we use bye array output stream to write directly into s3 bucket instead of writing into local disk and then putting into s3?

Comment: Added an example of sending as a stream.